# Add or subtract year from YMD based on values in another column

Tags: r

Seems simple but I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere. I have a large camera dataset with over one million rows. Some of the years were entered wrong for certain cameras. I want to add or subtract a year from my date columns based on the column ID. For example in the dataset below I would like to add one year in the deploy_start and deploy_end columns where ProjectCameraID == "OG2"

Here is an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  deploy_start = as.Date(c("2023-05-15", "2022-05-20", "2024-05-10")),
  deploy_end = as.Date(c("2023-09-15", "2022-09-20", "2024-09-10")),
  ProjectCameraID = c("OG1", "OG2", "OG3")                      
)
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

I have tried:

```
dep$deploy_start <- if(dep$ProjectCameraID == "OG2"){
  ymd(df$deploy_start) + years(1)
} else {
  ymd(dep$deploy_start)
}
```

but get error code:

```
Error in if (dep$ProjectCameraID == "OG2") { : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

Comment: You need the `ifelse()` function, not an `if {...} else {...}` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this quick-and-dirty with basic indexing:

```
changecols <- c("deploy_start", "deploy_end")

df[df$ProjectCameraID == "OG2", changecols] <- df[df$ProjectCameraID == "OG2", changecols] + 365
```

Although the `lubridate` package [using `%m+%](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35063465/12109788) may be more technically accurate and when dealing with leap years:

```
library(lubridate)
df[df$ProjectCameraID == "OG2", changecols] <- lapply(df[df$ProjectCameraID == "OG2", changecols], \(x) ymd(x) %m+% years(1))

#   deploy_start deploy_end ProjectCameraID
# 1   2023-05-15 2023-09-15             OG1
# 2   2023-05-20 2023-09-20             OG2
# 3   2024-05-10 2024-09-10             OG3
```

Output

```
  deploy_start deploy_end ProjectCameraID
1   2023-05-15 2023-09-15             OG1
2   2023-05-20 2023-09-20             OG2
3   2024-05-10 2024-09-10             OG3
```

Answer (score 0):

Next is one way of a tidyverse approach. You would choose the versions `start_v` and `end_v` that suit best for your actual purpose. Showing multiple versions of adding "one" year as well as expanding the data example originally presented is done with the idea of illustrating a few things you may want to consider.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
  deploy_start = as.Date(c("2023-05-15", "2022-05-20", "2024-05-10", "2024-02-28")),
  deploy_end = as.Date(c("2023-09-15", "2022-09-20", "2024-09-10", "2024-02-29")),
  ProjectCameraID = c("OG1", "OG2", "OG3", "OG4")                      
)

dat |> 
  mutate(
    start_v1 = case_when(
      ProjectCameraID %in% c("OG2", "OG4") ~ ymd(deploy_start) + years(1),
      .default = ymd(deploy_start)
    ),
    end_v1 = case_when(
      ProjectCameraID %in% c("OG2", "OG4") ~ ymd(deploy_end) + years(1),
      .default = ymd(deploy_end)
    ),
    start_v2 = case_when(
      ProjectCameraID %in% c("OG2", "OG4") ~ ymd(deploy_start) + days(365),
      .default = ymd(deploy_start)
    ),
    end_v2 = case_when(
      ProjectCameraID %in% c("OG2", "OG4") ~ ymd(deploy_end) + days(365),
      .default = ymd(deploy_end)
    ),
    start_v3 = case_when(
      ProjectCameraID %in% c("OG2", "OG4") ~ ymd(deploy_start) %m+% years(1),
      .default = ymd(deploy_start)
    ),
    end_v3 = case_when(
      ProjectCameraID %in% c("OG2", "OG4") ~ ymd(deploy_end) %m+% years(1),
      .default = ymd(deploy_end)
    )
  )

## gives:
#  deploy_start deploy_end ProjectCameraID   start_v1     end_v1   start_v2     end_v2   start_v3     end_v3
#1   2023-05-15 2023-09-15             OG1 2023-05-15 2023-09-15 2023-05-15 2023-09-15 2023-05-15 2023-09-15
#2   2022-05-20 2022-09-20             OG2 2023-05-20 2023-09-20 2023-05-20 2023-09-20 2023-05-20 2023-09-20
#3   2024-05-10 2024-09-10             OG3 2024-05-10 2024-09-10 2024-05-10 2024-09-10 2024-05-10 2024-09-10
#4   2024-02-28 2024-02-29             OG4 2025-02-28       <NA> 2025-02-27 2025-02-28 2025-02-28 2025-02-28
```